# Unable to use vi editor in wordpress container

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have been struggling to use `vi` editor in WordPress container (on Kubernetes) to edit a file `wp-config.php`
I am currently using this helm chart of WordPress from Artifactub:  https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/wordpress

Image: `docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6.1.1-debian-11-r1`

These are the errors I'm getting when trying to edit the `wp-config.php` inside the pod with either `vi` or `vim`

```bash
# vi wp-config.php

bash: vi: command not found
```

When I tried installing the `vi`, I get this error:

```bash
apt-get install vi

# Error
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Then I tried by first `ssh-ing` into the node hosting the WordPress pod, then exec into the container using docker with sudo privileges as shown below:

```bash
docker exec -it -u root <containerID> /bin/bash
```

I then tried installing the `vi` editor in the container by still getting this same error

The content I want to add to the `wp-config.php` is the following. It's a plugin requirement so that I can be able to store media files right into my AWS S3 bucket:

```bash
define('SSU_PROVIDER', 'aws');
define('SSU_BUCKET', 'my-bucket');
define('SSU_FOLDER', 'my-folder');
```

Can I run the command like this:

```bash
helm install my-wordpress bitnami/wordpress \
  --set mariadb.enabled=false \
  --set externalDatabase.host=my-host \
  --set externalDatabase.user=my-user \
  --set externalDatabase.password=my-password \
  --set externalDatabase.database=mydb \
  --set wordpressExtraConfigContent="define('SSU_PROVIDER', 'aws');define('SSU_BUCKET', 'my-bucket');define('SSU_FOLDER', 'my-folder');"
```

Comment: Build on top of wordpress image. But you really should not be editing anything inside container unless you are testing something in dev environment

Comment: But Is there a way I can add/edit the `wp-config.php` file? Better still, how can I use vi/vim in WordPress container. I think it's pretty standard to use vi/vim in a container and if necessary alter configurations in `wp-config.php` for wordpress developers

Comment: Well, it's up to you. In most of the cases it's NOT considered standard approach.  The pods are ephemeral in nature, they might get deleted and recreated for unlimited number of reasons. And the pods will loose the changes done by VIM.

Comment: Assuming the file system is not read only , you can either build your own image or use tools like `sed` to workaround the problem.

Comment: Great input on that. I agree that the ephemeral nature of the pod will make me lose the changes when the pod is deleted and recreated. Now can you help me with a way to edit the `wp-config.php` file from the pod spec section during the deployment creation? So it's get recreated on every new deployment

Comment: Consider adding the file before and after the change to the question. For getting aworking example. You can totally do this using volumes and configmap.

Comment: What are the changes that you want to make to wp-config file ?

Comment: The changes I want to add is `define('SSU_PROVIDER', 'aws');define('SSU_BUCKET', 'my-bucket');define('SSU_FOLDER', 'my-folder');`. Also refer to the question, I've updated it to have the full content I want to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fix for me after a marathon of different options was just to use a plugin to sync my media files with my AWS s3 bucket. There was literally no way for me to be able to do any function with the bitnami wordpress container. Can't edit nor install any edition (vi/vim/nano). It was locked and I didn't want to edit and build from their base image because we had running wordpress applications on a k8s cluster

This is the plugin that I used [media cloud](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ilab-media-tools/)

Answer (score 2):

In the chart documentation repository [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/wordpress) there are 2 possible ways to do it:
[image]

So, to the value files you could use `wordpressExtraConfigContent` variable and add extra content, or use the variable `wordpressConfiguration` to set a **new** `wp-config.php`

EDIT: You seem to be trying to define environment variables with php define, in that case you can pass environment variables to the pods with the variables:

So `--set extraEnvVars` or create a configmap with the variables that you want( would be better) and pass `--set extraEnvVarsCM <you-configmap>` (which will mount the configmap as an env var into the wordpress container.

[image]

Comment: This looks really interesting to implement. Will something like this look appropriate?
`helm install my-wordpress bitnami/wordpress \
  --set mariadb.enabled=false \
  --set externalDatabase.host=my-host \
  --set externalDatabase.user=my-user \
  --set externalDatabase.password=my-password \
  --set externalDatabase.database=mydb \
  --set wordpressExtraConfigContent="define('SSU_PROVIDER', 'aws');define('SSU_BUCKET', 'my-bucket');define('SSU_FOLDER', 'my-folder');"`

The whole idea is to add this extra content to the `wp-config.php`

Comment: I've updated the question so you can see that part

Comment: still waiting for you

Comment: i already updated about 4 hours ago

Comment: Great, I'll do that and revert

Comment: I tried all these, it just didn't workd